# Access different columns from LINQ resultset

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a query which returns multiple columns from the database using LINQ

```
var donors = from d2 in db.Donors
                 where d2.Status == "Pending"
                 select new { donorID = d2.donorID, bloodGroup = d2.bloodGroup, contactNo = d2.contactMobile, status = d2.Status };
```

now I want to display the results in different `Labels` accessing one column value from `donors` resultset.

ex:

`Label1.Text = donorID;
Label2.Text = bloodGroup;` ...and so on

please help me achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to set a label to a value, you'll need a *single* record. Currently you're selecting a *sequence* of records. Let's suppose you're only interested in the first value. You could write:

```
var donors = from d2 in db.Donors
             where d2.Status == "Pending"
             select new { d2.donorID, d2.bloodGroup, 
                          contactNo = d2.contactMobile, status = d2.Status };

var firstDonor = donors.FirstOrDefault();
if (firstDonor != null)
{
    Label1.Text = firstDonor.donorID;
    Label2.Text = firstDonor.bloodGroup;
    // ...
}
else
{
    // There weren't any matching donors
}
```

If you want to display *all* the donor details, you'll want something more like a grid.

Comment: that means if I convert this resultset into `DataTable` then I'll be able to access each and every single value from it. If thats the case then how do I convert it into `DataTable`

Comment: @Piyush: While you *could* convert it into a `DataTable`, there's little point. You could just call `donors.ToList()` at which point you'll have a list of your anonymous type. If you need to access that in a strongly-typed way outside your current method, it would be worth creating a new type to encapsulate the properties you're interested, and convert your results into a list of that type.

Comment: do you have any suggestion regarding this question http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=httphandler%20asp.net

Comment: @gov: You didn't link to a particular question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time Jon. I wanted to display all the donor details so i used `DataTable` and it turned out to be working perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist in keeping the labels, you could do something like this

```
var donors = from d2 in db.Donors
             where d2.Status == "Pending"
             select d2;

List<Donors> myDonors = donors.ToList();

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        foreach (var donor in donors)
        {
            Label myLabel = new Label();
            myLabel.Top = x;
            myLabel.Left = y;
            myLabel.Text = donor.donorID.ToString();
            panel1.Controls.Add(myLabel);
            y += myLabel.Width + 5;

            myLabel = new Label();
            myLabel.Top = x;
            myLabel.Left = y;
            myLabel.Text = donor.blodGroup.ToString();
            panel1.Controls.Add(myLabel);
            y += myLabel.Width + 5;

            myLabel = new Label();
            myLabel.Top = x;
            myLabel.Left = y;
            myLabel.Text = donor.contactNo.ToString();
            panel1.Controls.Add(myLabel);
            y += myLabel.Width + 5;

            myLabel = new Label();
            myLabel.Top = x;
            myLabel.Left = y;
            myLabel.Text = donor.status.ToString();
            panel1.Controls.Add(myLabel);
            y += myLabel.Width + 5;


            y = 0;
            x += myLabel.Height + 5;
        }
```

Comment: thats a lot of code buddy... my work is done by converting the resultset into DataTable

Comment: im am aware of that.. i was only suggesting this as a way of sticking with the labels instead of a DataTable